# Can anyone explain the compute(fn func()) code in the Go Tour website?

Tags: go, closures

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func compute(fn func(float64, float64) float64) float64 {
    return fn(3, 4)
}

func main() {
    hypot := func(x, y float64) float64 {
        return math.Sqrt(x*x + y*y)
    }
    fmt.Println(hypot(5, 12))

    fmt.Println(compute(hypot))
    fmt.Println(compute(math.Pow))
}
```

Is the fn func() a function inside a function?? Can someone help with what is exactly the func compute doing here?. And I'm quite new to GO programming.

Comment: _Functions are values too. They can be passed around just like other values.
Function values may be used as function arguments and return values._ - what is you dont understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A closure is a function value that references variables from outside
>   its body. The function may access and assign to the referenced
>   variables; in this sense the function is "bound" to the variables.

In your case, compute contains a closure function. Function is passed to the `compute` function as an argument whose returned value is `float64` which is then called in the compute function.

```
func compute(fn func(float64, float64) float64) float64 {
     return fn(3, 4) // calling the function.
}
```

Since there are two functions created with same number of arguments, one of which is `hypot`.

```
hypot := func(x, y float64) float64 {
    return math.Sqrt(x*x + y*y)
}
```

which takes two `float64` values as an argument and then returns a `float64` value, while another function is in package [`math`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/#Pow) of golang which is `math.pow`

```
func Pow(x, y float64) float64 // Pow returns x**y, the base-x exponential of y.
```

whose definition is similar, which let us two pass any type of function as an argument to the compute function.

Take for an example on [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/NkW_KC3iSYp)

Comment: "compute is returning a closure function" compute is not returning a function, it is returning a value. It takes a closure as a parameter though.

Comment: @MadWombat that is a closure. you can check it here in the golang tour. https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/25

Comment: No. In that link, adder() returns a closure. And it is defined to return a closure. Here, the compute function is defined to return a float. And it returns a float.

Comment: @MadWombat compute also returning the closure which returns a float64 value. it is the same as mentioned in link except the link contains anonymous function.

Comment: Dude, literally, compute in the code above is defined as `compute(fn func(float64, float64) float64) float64` it takes a `func(float64, float64) float64` and returns `float64`. In your example, adder is defined as `func adder() func(int) int` it takes no arguments and returns a `func(int) int`. I think you are not counting parentheses right or something.

Comment: @MadWombat I agree with you but if it is not taking func as an argument that does not mean it is not a closure. you should read about closure what closure actually means does passing a func as an argument deny that it is not a closure.

Comment: No, just because something doesn't take arguments doesn't mean it is not closure. But closure, almost by definition, has to return a function. And compute() doesn't. Compute takes a function, calls it and returns a result. Adder actually returns a function with the result of that function calculated using the internal state of the adder. That makes adder a closure, but not compute. Compute is just a sort of an eval() for functions.

Comment: Actually, my last comment is somewhat incorrect. The closure, by definition, needs to close over something. Adder closes over the sum value and returns a function that uses the sum value to calculate its result. But compute doesn't actually close over anything, it just calls the function it is passed and returns its result.